# How are the equivalence classes made of orbits defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I am reading through Freileigh, and I'm curious to know if I am understanding the definition correctly.

Each Permutation of a set $A$ determines a natural partition of $A$ into cells with the property that $a, b\in A$ are in the same cell if and only if $f^n(a)=b$ for some $n$ that's an element of $\mathbb Z$.

Is this saying for every permutation of the set $A$, where each permutation is being represented by $f^n$ for integers $n$?

Say I had two permutation of $S_4$: 
$f^0$ and $f^1$

$f^0 = (1\mapsto1,\ 2\mapsto2,\ 3\mapsto3,\ 4\mapsto4)$

$f^1 = ( 1\mapsto2,\ 2\mapsto4, \ 3\mapsto1,\ 4\mapsto3 )$

The orbits of $f^0 = \{1\} \{2\} \{3\} \{4\}$
The orbits of $f^1 = \{1, 2, 4, 3\}$

Are the orbits of $f^0$ and $f^1$ in the same equivalence class or cell? When are two or more different permutations orbits in the same equivalence class?

Answer (score 2):

For a permutation $f$, *i.e.* a bijective map $f\colon A\to A$, the notation $f^n$ denotes the $n$-fold composition of $f$ with itself. For example $f^3$ is the permutation that maps $a\in A$ to $f(f(f(a)))$ and $f^{-2}$ is the permutation that maps $a\in A$ to $f^{-1}(f^{-1}(a))$, where $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of the bijective map $f$. To find the orbits of a permutation $f\colon A\to A$, look at some $a\in A$ and apply $f$ until you get back to $a$, all the elements you encounter in between are in the orbit of $a$. (If $A$ is infinite, you might never come back to $a$, then the orbit of $a\in A$ really needs to be described as $\{f^k(a)\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$)

You are asking the wrong questions:

> Are the orbits of $f^0$ and $f^1$ in the same equivalence class or cell? When are two or more different permutations orbits in the same equivalence class?

The equivalence classes here consist of *elements of $A$*, not of orbits. The equivalence classes **are** the orbits, or cells!

Two elements $a, b\in A$ are in the same orbit *of a permutation $f$*, or same equivalence classe, or same cell if and only if $f^k(a)=b$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: So when talking  about Orbits, we are only talking about one permutation of the Set A? What about all the other permutations of the set? How do they relate to the definition? From what I read in th definition, it says each permutation of the set A divides the Set into natural equivalence classes.

Comment: Yes! For each permutation you get a (possibly) different partition of $A$ into orbits.

Comment: Ah okay. I get it then. Thanks Christoph